# Uniqueness of Data metric

Tags: machine-learning, statistical-significance, mathematical-statistics, descriptive-statistics

Is there a metric that calculates "uniqueness of data"? For example if i have two sets of 200 observations,

DataSet 1 has 70 unique values but 4 values take up the next 130 observations. DataSet 2 has 60 unique values but no value is seen more than 4 times.

DataSet 2 would score higher for "uniqueness".

Answer (score 3):

This would really depend on how you would define "uniqueness". Are you evaluating the rate of single observations ? Or the distribution of your dataset, and more precisely, the distribution of its distinct values (which is what you seem to describe) ? What would be the mathematical rule which defines that a dataset is more "unique" compared to another one ?

Given what you have described, I assume that the (sorted) proportion of values would give information on what you call the "uniqueness" of the data. Example with R code.

```
set.seed(1)
dataset <- data.frame(df1 = c(rep(c(0,1), 40), rep(c(2,3),30), round(runif(60,5,65),0)), 
                      df2 = round(runif(200,1,40),0))
prop.table(table(dataset$df1))[order(prop.table(table(dataset$df1)))]
prop.table(table(dataset$df2))[order(prop.table(table(dataset$df2)))]
```

Which prompts the following results.

```
> prop.table(table(dataset$df1))[order(prop.table(table(dataset$df1)))]

13    18    20    24    25    27    29    30    31    36    37    38    39    41    43    46    47    49    51    53 
0.005 0.005 0.005 0.005 0.005 0.005 0.005 0.005 0.005 0.005 0.005 0.005 0.005 0.005 0.005 0.005 0.005 0.005 0.005 0.005 
54    55    61    62    65     6     9    11    16    17    21    35    44    48    57    59    34    45    52    28 
0.005 0.005 0.005 0.005 0.005 0.010 0.010 0.010 0.010 0.010 0.010 0.010 0.010 0.010 0.010 0.010 0.015 0.015 0.015 0.020 
2     3     0     1 
0.150 0.150 0.200 0.200


> prop.table(table(dataset$df2))[order(prop.table(table(dataset$df2)))]

27     2    32    33    39    40     3     4    13    22    28     7    10    15    25    30     6     9    17    23 
0.005 0.010 0.010 0.010 0.010 0.010 0.015 0.015 0.015 0.015 0.015 0.020 0.020 0.020 0.020 0.020 0.025 0.025 0.025 0.025 
34    36     5     8    12    18    24    35    16    20    38    19    21    29    31    37    11    14    26 
0.025 0.025 0.030 0.030 0.030 0.030 0.030 0.030 0.035 0.035 0.035 0.040 0.040 0.040 0.040 0.040 0.045 0.045 0.045
```

You can see that `df1` has more distinct values than `df2` but their distribution is concentrated in a few values in `df1` (0-3) whereas it is more uniform for `df2`. Yet, because the top values of `df2` proportion is (way) lower than `df1`, we could presumably state that `df2` is more "unique". This can also be seen graphically through bar charts.

[image]

The question is, which difference rate between top values is acceptable to define "uniqueness" ? This would be subject to debate, as the rate would be more than likely dependent on the number of evaluated observations.